# Azure managed NFS shared storage for Azure VMs

Tags: azure, storage

What is a reliable way to implement Azure managed NFS shared for multiple Azure VMs? 
The idea is an alternative to AWS EFS for multiple EC2. 
I only found the following solutions with disadvantages:

- [Azure NetApp files](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/netapp/) - minimum of **4TiB** and it asks to contact sales.
- [Azure shared disks](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/disks-shared#linux) - it has "maxShares limit".
- [Azure files NFS](https://aka.ms/AzureNFSPreview) - It's in preview.
- [SoftNAS on Azure](https://www.buurst.com/products/softnas/softnas-on-microsoft-azure/) - It doesn't make sense to provision 2 SoftNAS for HA for a small amount of storage.

So how do companies get an alternative solution to AWS EFS on Azure which makes sense?

Comment: You can try out Buurst SoftNAS. www.buurst.com Less costly than ANF or EFS and outperforms almost 15-20x faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure files NFS share documentation was just uploaded:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-how-to-create-nfs-shares

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure Files

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-introduction

Limits for it can be found from here

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-files-scale-targets

Comment: The original Azure files service currently doesn't support NFS. Only SMB. There's only Azure files NFS is in preview.

Comment: what are you trying to share BTW, what will the usage be?

Comment: Trying to understand how to build a scalable LAMP environment on Azure. On AWS it's very clear since you can mount EFS to EC2 instances.

Comment: this might completely irrelevant so apologies in advance. You can do App Service (Web Apps in Linux) and also in Containers for Web Apps as well, also PHP in app services works fine and lastly MySQL for which Azure has a platform service which would be way cheaper to use compared to VMs. But for your original question do you think [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-how-to-use-files-linux#mounting-azure-file-share) will work for you.